# "Cannot read git config" when configuring Git default remote and merge

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I´m using EGit with eclipse to sync my dev environment to two different computer. I have a slight problem with the one where I originally created by project and pushed it to my remote git repo (which happens to be github).

Now I searched the web and found some pointers indicating that I have to add to key/value pairs myself to the config file. The keys are branch.master.merge and branch.master.remote

My config now looks like this:

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
logallrefupdates = true
autocrlf = false
[remote "origin"]
url = https://dan-lind@github.com/dan-lind/prime-sweet.git
fetch = refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

The info I found was to add the follwing lines:

```
branch.master.merge = refs/heads/master
branch.master.remote = origin
```

Question: Where am I supposed to put them? I tried putting them both under the core and under the remote sections, but as soon as I fire up Eclipse I get an error message saying that the git config file cannot be read. If I remove the two lines again, everything is fine (except that I still have no defaults and cannot use pull)

Any suggestions?
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `branch.master` translates to a section called `[branch "master"]`. So you get:

```
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

Another option is to use the config command of git:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put theses informations in this way in your config file:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

But you shouldn't have to edit this file manually.
There are different ways to make git configure this tracking for you :

- When you clone a remote repository, the tracking of the master branch is automatically configured
- When you create a local branch, you can specify the tracking with the "--track" option :

`git branch local --track origin/local`

- If you push a branch with the "-u" option, it will enable the tracking between your local branch and the remote you pushed to :

`git push -u origin master`